# Denumerable Subelements of a Boolean Algebra

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

Say that $x$ is a **subelement** of $y$ if $y$ dominates $x$, i.e., $x\leq y$, where $x$ and $y$ are members of a boolean algebra, and say that $x$ is a **proper subelement** of $y$ if additionally $x\neq y$.

My question is: If there is a member $z$ of a boolean algebra (keeping in mind that this boolean algebra is not necessarily complete) that dominates infinitely many atoms, is there always a proper subelement of $z$ that dominates denumerably many atoms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  For instance, let $X$ be an uncountable set and consider the Boolean algebra of subsets of $X$ that are finite or cofinite.  The atoms are then the singletons so any cofinite set dominates infinitely many atoms, but no element dominates countably infinitely many atoms.